# Show my DrawerLayoutAndroid , onPress (rightButton) from NavigationBarRouteMapper

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I have a very litle problem...

I have a `<DrawerLayoutAndroid>` and a `Navigator` and from the right button of my `var NavigationBarRouteMapper`, I want to show the drawer... basics ! 
But when I click, nothings gets done ....

---

I tried this, but it's not the same configuration, doesn't work for me....

[this refs is getting undefined in method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31986126/this-refs-is-getting-undefined-in-method)

---

Here is my NavigationBarRouteMapper :

`var NavigationBarRouteMapper = {
    LeftButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
        return (*something*);
    },
    RightButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
        return(
                <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                   <Icon.Button name="bars" color="white" backgroundColor="#246dd5"              onPress={this.openDrawer}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>);
    },
    Title(route, navigator, index, navState) {
        return (*something*);
    }
};`

---

And my NavigationBarRouteMapper works because leftButton works(i don't paste the code here), so it's just the call to OnPress() from RightButton that i don't succeed to do...

And here is my DrawerDeclaration :

`<DrawerLayoutAndroid
                drawerWidth={300}
                ref={'DRAWER_REF'}
                navigator={Navigator.SceneConfigs.HorizontalSwipeJump}
                drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
                renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}>            </DrawerLayoutAndroid>`

---

And at end my function'call :

`openDrawer:function() {
         this.refs['DRAWER_REF'].openDrawer();
  },`

---

NOTE : That when i do `this.refs['DRAWER_REF'].openDrawer();` inside my class, it's working, but NavigationRouteMapper isn't, of course, inside it :) So it's really just the link between my class and NavigationBarRouteMapper....

thank's to red it !

Comment: Hey, can you post how you push new routes onto the stack? I have an idea how to make it working (had similar case), but would like to see that snippet first.

Comment: It's not a problem, my push in my navigatorRouteMapper woks well... I did them like that : `onPress={() =>navigator.parentNavigator.push({id: 'Movie'})}` . And I almost resolve my problem, I understood, how to passing method to route in renderMethod... `render: function()
    {
        return (<Navigator
              initialRoute={{onRightButton: (() => Alert.alert("Ok"})}} And if I call in NavRouteMapper like that : onPress={route.onRightButton}, my alert is displayed, but if I put `this.refs.drawer.openDrawer()` I got `undefined is not an object (evaluating this.refs.drawer.openDrawer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it !!!!

I just had to declare my `<DrawerLayoutAndroid>` in the render method instead of declare it in anothe method call in render()... So it give this... :

`render: function()
    {

    var navigationView = (
            <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
            <Text style={{margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'left'}}>I'm in the Drawer!</Text>
            </View>
        );
        return(
            <DrawerLayoutAndroid
                drawerWidth={300}
                ref={'drawer'}
                navigator={Navigator.SceneConfigs.HorizontalSwipeJump}
                drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
                renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}>
                <Navigator /****/ />
            </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
          );
    },`

:) !